# Bash Script for ExpressVPN

Tags: linux, shell-script, gnome-terminator, launcher

I am currently struggling to run a custom expressVPN script that will run several commands one after the other when I click on the launcher (that links to the script)

I have so far managed to get terminator to start, stay open and run the command to start EVPN , however I cannot type in the terminal, nor can I figure out why I can't add extra commands without it going haywire.

```
#!/bin/bash
terminator -e expressvpn -p hold
```

What id like to achieve is open the terminal , run more commands, whilst showing the command before, and be able to keep the terminal open so I can type extra in.

Any advice would be v appreciated. I have tried a lot of combinations, to no avail.

Thanks ☺️

Comment: I presume `expressvpn` is a command that keeps running (this is probably the reason why you can't run any more commands). You'd need to either launch it in background or open another terminal.

Comment: Simple example with two tabs: `terminator -e expressvpn &; terminator --new-tab -e /bin/bash` Instead of `;` you can just put a new line in the script. `&` at the end of the line will allow the script to move on before completing the command. **Note:** This will not wait for a connection to be established.

Comment: Thanks for replying Rudib. Much appreciated. One thing I will say is that if I already have a terminal open and run expressvpn i can enter additional commands. Eg expressvpn status. It doesn't necessarily have to be in terminator. Do you have an idea of an alternative command that can open a terminal, keep it open, run one command show results then run another command in that same terminal?

Comment: I had a look at the expressvpn cli and it doesn't seem like it's supposed to keep running. You're just sending commands to the daemon. I presume by `expressvpn` you mean `expressvpn connect` or similar? Also, could you specify what you mean by "haywire"? I suspect that it's the window closing?

Comment: Hi, great - then we've located the issue.

Comment: Hi rudib , apologies. Yeah it does just close. When it comes to expressvpn you enter the initial command in the terminal and you get given a list of commands to enter. What id like is for that to come up (which I can do) but then enter more commands from that same terminal screen. I am currently trying your your commands currently ensuring I use  -p hold             at the end to no avail.

Comment: Ah I see, I've updated my answer - it should still work. I thought you wanted to connect, but it can display the help too, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `terminator -e` will specify the command to be run in the terminal (this will not run in a shell - meaning that once the command is finished, there's no reason to keep the terminal open). And since `expressvpn` doesn't provide a shell, you can't really type anything while it runs either.

Usually, you'd use `terminator -e /bin/bash`. Bash probably is your default shell and will keep running until you type exit.

If I understood correctly, you basically want to run a command in the terminal and start a shell later, so this should be what terminator should run: `yourcommand; /bin/bash`

So this should do the trick:

```
terminator -e "command; /bin/bash"
```

Replace `command` with your command as needed (e.g.: `expressvpn --help`).

---

If you want to add a lot more commands, you may want to use a script instead:

```
terminator -e /path/to/my/script.sh
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#display help
expressvpn --help

#other commands

#start interactive shell (for manual input of commands)
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Rudib you are a star!! I have to ask though , what was the point of the "-p hold" I read about, and what is the relevance of putting /bin/bash at the end? And if I want to add more commands, can I just put one after the other before the closed quotations?

Comment: you can set profiles in the terminator preferences. In the tab command, you can set "When the command exits" to `hold`. I suppose if you created a profile with the name `hold` with that setting and then select it with `-p hold`, the terminal will stay open when the command is finished (but that won't allow you to run commands afterwards, but you can inspect the output).

Comment: if you want to add more commands, you can add them before `/bin/bash` as this will start the interactive shell (where you can run commands indefinately - unitil you type exit or similar). But if you want to add a lot of cammands, you can add a script instead. I'll update my answer on that.

Comment: Oh that's really annoying, is ``` -p hold``` the command for selecting a profile called hold .......?

Comment: Yes, seems to be that way. `-p` just accesses a profile with the specified name. And will therefore only work if it exists and is set up in the way you'd expect...

Comment: Lol, I can't believe I didn't clock that. Thanks rudib. I've just tried running 3 EVPN commands and they all show up one after the other which is perfect. Much appreciated. With what you've shown me im going to play with other stuff now too.

Comment: Rudib thank you so much for your responses,they have been invaluable. I've been playing about with scripts as well and am enjoying what can be done. much much appreciated!